# How would I go about creating this class precisely?

Tags: java

I have a good idea about what I need to do in order to create this next method that searches for a course within the program listed below, but I am a noob and do not have the skills to precisely put it out into the exact words.  please someone help? You don't have to give me exact method if you want, just guide me at least. I have another method I have to create as well but first lets work with this.

Here is the problem:
Program 5 
Program Assignment:
Add two more methods to the Class Student.  One that will search the student's schedule for a course and one that will allow the User to drop a course.  The name of the first method will be dropCourse and the name of the second method will be searchCourse.  
Be sure to test both methods thoroughly.  Add a menu to the Driver to allow the user to thoroughly test each method:
1.  Add a course
2.  Search for a course
3.  Drop a course
4.  Print out student's schedule

Searching for a Course
The assignment in this module calls for including a method that searches for a course name in the array containing the students schedule.  This method will not return a value - it will be void.  It will have the name of the course you want to search for as a string parameter in the parameter list.  It will search the array and print out one of two messages - either it found the course or it didn't.
To search for a course in the array that contains the student's schedule, you want to search until you find the course name you are looking for or until you reach the last course in the array. 
NOTE:  You are not searching until you reach the end of the array - rather you are searching until you reach the LAST COURSE stored in the array.  If an array is not full when the search is performed it must stop at the last course in the array or else you will have a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION.  This error occurs if an empty cell in an array is accessed for a comparison or a print (it can also occur when you try to read beyond the size of an array).  Therefore, you only want to search array cells that have data in them.  For this program, you do not want to search beyond "courseNumber" because this variable contains the number of courses in the array.
This means that you will set up a WHILE loop that has two conditions - one condition is a sentinel that starts out as FALSE and is changed to TRUE if the course name is found.  The other condition is to search until you are at the last course in the array.   In essence, you are searching until one of these two conditions becomes true - you'll either find the course or you'll reach the last course in the array without finding the course.  This means that you are creating a WHILE loop with two conditions - one is a sentinel and one is a counter.  The sentinel tells you if the course is found and the counter tells you if you've reached the last course stored in the array.
To set up the sentinel condition - searching until you find the course - you will need to create a sentinel.  In your data declaration section, declare a Boolean variable named flag.  Then initialize it to false.  
To set up the counting condition - so you can stop if you've reached the last course in the array without finding the course you are searching for - you need to set up a counter.  In your data declaration section, declare an integer variable and call it index.  
Then, set up the WHILE loop condition like this:
     set flag equal to false
     set index equal to 0
     WHILE (index is less than number of courses in array AND flag == false)
The first thing you want to do is to extract the course name from the string in the array.  To do this, you use the substring method.  If you look at Module 3, the substring method is described like so:
            String substring (int offset, int endIndex)
It returns a portion of the string that starts at the value of offset and ends at the value of endIndex.  
The course name that you want to extract from the schedule array is the first 6 characters in the array.  To extract it, use 0 for the offset and 6 for the endIndex. 
When you extract the course name, you want to place it in a temporary string to compare it to the course you are searching for.  Set it up like so:
            tempString = schedule[index].substring(0,6);

The next task is to then compare the extracted string to the course name you are searching for.  If the two strings are equal, then you are done searching.  To indicate you are done, change the Boolean flag to true.  If the two strings are not equal, then increment the index value so you can look in the next position within the array. 
Putting this all together, the algorithm for this method is as follows:

set flag equal to false

set index equal to 0

WHILE (index is less than number of courses in array AND flag == false)

extract substring

IF ( string1.equals(string2) == true ) THEN //course found

set flag to true

ELSE   
                        increment index
            END IF

END WHILE

IF flag == false THEN

display message the course name was not found

ELSE

course name found at position index

END IF
 
To call this in the Driver, you would first prompt the User for the course name they wish to search for.  Then simply call the searchCourse method and send it the course name.  After searching for the course, the searchCourse method will print out one of two messages – either the course was found or that it wasn’t found.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//This is a Driver program to test the external Class named Student
public class StudentDriver //BEGIN Class Definition
{
   //****************  Main Method*************************
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   //Data Definitions:
   //Instance Data
   String courseName;
   int courseCredits;

   String name;
   String id;
   String street;
   String city;
   String state;
   String zip;
   String major;

   //Executable Statements:
   //Initialize first Student
   name = "Fred Fergel";
   id = "0123";
   street = "123 Main Street";
   city = "Smalltown";
   state = "NY";
   zip = "12345";
   major = "Computer Science";
   //instantiate the Student object
   Student student1 = new Student(name, id, street, city, state, zip, major);
   //Test toString
   System.out.println("Student 1\n\n" + student1.toString());
   //Print a blank line
   System.out.println();
   //Add a course
   student1.addCourse("CSC111", 4);//NOTE:  DO NOT PUT A SPACE BETWEEN CSC AND 111
   //Print schedule
   System.out.println("Student 1's Schedule:\n\n");
   student1.displaySchedule();//call method

   final String FLAG = "Y";
     String prompt = "Y";
   while (prompt.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
   {
   System.out.println("Please enter the name of the course: ");
   courseName = scan.next();
   System.out.println("How many credits is the course? ");
   courseCredits = scan.nextInt();
   student1.addCourse(courseName, courseCredits);
   System.out.println("Do you wish to enter another course? y/n");
   prompt = scan.next();
   }
   //end while
```

Student class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Student
{Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   //Instance Data
   String studentName;
   String studentID;
   String streetAddress;
   String city;
   String state;
   String zipCode;
   String major;
   int  totalCredits;
   final int SIZE = 6;
   final int MAX_CREDITS = 18;
   String [ ] schedule = new String [SIZE];
   int courseNumber = 0; //start out with no courses
   //Create Constructor:
   //Initializes the student data at instantiation time.
   //-------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sets up the student's information.
   //-------------------------------------------------------
   public Student (String name, String id, String address, String cityName, String stateName, String zip, String area )
   {
   studentName = name;
   studentID = id;
   streetAddress = address;
   city = cityName;
   state = stateName;
   zipCode = zip;
   major = area;
   }//end Student Constructor
   //Method to Return student information as string:
   //-------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the student information as a formatted string.
   //-------------------------------------------------------
   public String toString()
   {
   String studentInfo;
   studentInfo = "Name:\t\t\t" + studentName + "\n" + "ID:\t\t\t" + studentID + "\n" + "Address:\t\t" + streetAddress
   + "\n" + "City:\t\t\t" + city + "\n" + "State:\t\t\t" + state + "\n" + "Zip Code:\t\t" + zipCode
   + "\n" + "Major:\t\t\t" + major + "\n";
   return studentInfo;
}// end toString
   //Method to determine if maximum allowed credits have been exceeded
   //-------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns true if total credits does not exceed 18.
   //-------------------------------------------------------
   private boolean checkCredits(int numCredits)
   {
   if (numCredits + totalCredits <= MAX_CREDITS)  //make sure max credits not exceeded
   {
   return true;  //return a true if still less than 18 credits
                     }
   else
   {
   return false;  //return a false if 18 credit limit is exceeded
   }//end numCredits
   }//checkCredits
   //Method to add a course to the student’s schedule
   //-------------------------------------------------------
   //  Adds a course to the array if total credits does not exceed 18.
   //-------------------------------------------------------
   public void addCourse(String course, int numCredits)
   {
   if (courseNumber <  SIZE )  //make sure array is not full.  
   {
   if (checkCredits(numCredits) == true) //if we’re under 18 credits
   {
   //add course
   schedule [courseNumber] = course + ":\t\t" + numCredits + "\tCredits\n";
   //increment number of credits
   totalCredits = totalCredits + numCredits;
   //increment number of courses
   courseNumber = courseNumber + 1;
   }
   else  //oops – can’t do more than 18 credits
   {
   System.out.println("You have exceeded the maximum allowed credits.");
   }//end checkCredits
   }
   else  //oops – can’t do more than 10 courses
   {
   System.out.println("You have exceeded 10 courses.");
   }//end courseNumber
   }//addCourse
   //Method to display the schedule
   //-------------------------------------------------------
   //  Will only print out the courses added to the array.
   //-------------------------------------------------------
   public void displaySchedule( )
   {
   for (int index = 0; index < courseNumber; index++)
   {
   System.out.println("Course #" + (index + 1) + " " + schedule[index] + "\n");
   }//end for
   }//end display schedule


   //   set flag equal to false
   //      set index equal to 0
   //      WHILE (index is less than number of courses in array AND flag == false)
   //             extract substring
   //             IF ( string1.equals(string2) == true ) THEN //course found
   //                         set flag to true
   //             ELSE   
   //                         increment index
   //             END IF
   //       END WHILE
   //       IF flag == false THEN
   //             display message the course name was not found
   //       ELSE
   //             course name found at position index 
   //       END IF
   //  

   final String FLAG = false;
     String prompt = "Y";
   while (prompt.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
   {

      }//end main
   }//end StudentDriver

}
```

errors:

```
Student.java:118: error: '(' expected
    int index = 0;
    ^
Student.java:120: error: illegal start of type
   while (index < numCourses || FLAG = false; index++)
   ^
Student.java:120: error: > expected
   while (index < numCourses || FLAG = false; index++)
                             ^
Student.java:120: error: ')' expected
   while (index < numCourses || FLAG = false; index++)
                               ^
Student.java:120: error: ';' expected
   while (index < numCourses || FLAG = false; index++)
                                    ^
Student.java:120: error: illegal start of type
   while (index < numCourses || FLAG = false; index++)
                                       ^
Student.java:120: error: <identifier> expected
   while (index < numCourses || FLAG = false; index++)
                                            ^
Student.java:120: error: ';' expected
   while (index < numCourses || FLAG = false; index++)
                                             ^
Student.java:120: error: illegal start of type
   while (index < numCourses || FLAG = false; index++)
                                                   ^
Student.java:120: error: <identifier> expected
   while (index < numCourses || FLAG = false; index++)
                                                     ^
Student.java:120: error: ';' expected
   while (index < numCourses || FLAG = false; index++)
                                                      ^
Student.java:134: error: class, interface, or enum expected
   if
   ^
Student.java:138: error: class, interface, or enum expected
   else
   ^
13 errors
```

tried your method, erros followed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear from the question how you want to implement this algorithm, but the Java way to implement your pseudocode would look something like this (assuming I understand your existing code properly):

```
    boolean flag = false;
    int index = 0;
    while(index < schedule.length && !flag) {
        String substring = schedule[index];
        if (substring.equals(otherString)) {
            flag = true;
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    }
    if (!flag) {
        // display message that the course name was not found 
    } else {
        courseName = schedule[index];
    }
```

I would note a few things:

In a conditional, you don't have to say "== true"

```
if (string1.equals(string2) == true)
```

You could just write

```
if (string1.equals(string2))
```

Also, in your code, you write "String FLAG = false;"  You should make FLAG a boolean, not a String.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question to be more specific as to what problem you're having and where it's happening in the code.  Otherwise, as @JoeC points out, this is off-topic for the site